# Selecting from an array of objects, by matching a property within, which is also an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, filtering, data-retrieval

Forgive the title, but basically this is what I'm trying to do:

I have an array of objects, lets call them dogs for this example. Each object looks something like this:

```
    {
        name: "Poodle",
        keywords: ["Fluffy", "Intelligent", "Hypo-allergenic", "Loyal"]
    }
```

The user picks three words, and then I want to search the array of objects, and match these three words against the 'keywords' property on each array. Then I have some display logic:

- If the dog matches on all three of the users chosen words, I only want to return that one dog.
- If there are only dogs that match on 2 words, then I want to bring a max of 2 of these dogs.
- If there is only a single 2-word dog and then multiple 1 dog matches, just show the 2 word dog.
- If there are only 1-word dog matches, then show a maximum of three of these.

Basically, I'm not asking how to do the bullet points, I can figure that out, but ideally I need an array of dogs and number of matches next to each one. I can then do some filtering on this.

**So I need an array of dog names**, with a match total, something like this ( unless of course there is a better way then I'm all ears ):

```
[
  ["Poodle", 2],
  ["Labrador", 2],
  ["Schpitz", 1],
  ["Setter", 0],
  ["Pit Bull", 0]
]
```

Does this sound like the best approach, or is there a simpler/better way?

Comment: It seems all right to me, maybe if you need to do this multiple times, index the dogs.

Comment: Thanks, I have bolded the thing I'm actually trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

No it does not sound like the best approach, because you are saving something that is essentially an object in an array structure. A better approach would be to make an array of result objects as the outcome.

With the following snippet you get an array of objects consisting of the dog name and all the matched keywords.

You can easily get the number of keywords matched from it (by using `result[i].matched.length`), but I think this is more practical, as you can also show which keywords actually matched.

```js
const data = [
  {
    name: "Poodle",
    keywords: ["Fluffy", "Intelligent", "Hypo-allergenic", "Loyal"]
  },
  {
    name: "Husky",
    keywords: ["Fluffy", "Cute", "Stuff", "IdkMuchAboutDogs"]
  }
];

const keywords = ["Fluffy", "Cute", "Intelligent"];

const result = data.map(dog => {
  return {
    dog: dog.name,
    matches: keywords.filter(keyword => dog.keywords.indexOf(keyword) !== -1)
  };
});

console.log(result);
```

If you want to have more logic on the keyword comparing, you need to do something like

```
...
matches: keywords.filter(keyword => 
   dog.keywords.filter(dogkeyword => 
      // Now you can compare those two keywords with more complex algorithms
      dogkeyword.toLowerCase() == keyword.toLowerCase()
   ).length !== 0
)
...
```

or similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate score by your wish:

```
let dogs = [
    {
        name: "Poodle",
        keywords: ["Fluffy", "Intelligent", "Hypo-allergenic", "Loyal"]
    },
    {
        name: "Dog2",
        keywords: ["Fluffy", "Intelligent", "Hypo-allergenic",]
    },
    {
        name: "Dog3",
        keywords: ["Fluffy"]
    }
]
```

The scoring:

```
let scored = words => dogs.map(dog => {
    // you can add modification for 2 words term
    let score = dog.keywords.filter(kw => words.includes(kw)).length

    return {
        name: dog.name,
        score
    }
})
```

And then sort by best score:

```
let sorted = dogs => dogs.sort((a,b) => b.score - a.score)
console.log(sorted(scored(['Fluffy', 'Loyal', "Intelligent"])))

{name: "Poodle", score: 3}
{name: "Dog2", score: 2}
{name: "Dog3", score: 1}
```

It's not optimal but you can modify it as you go.